"docker image history" is missing digests for layers that we've built locally
I'm trying to find my way back to the digest of a base image in order to pin it and avoid some problematic upstream changes (in AWS Lambda). However, only the first layer has an ID (which is a digest, here) while none of the rest of our own layers (the top eleven are ours) do:
IMAGE          CREATED       CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
753335235a5f   2 weeks ago   RUN /bin/sh -c pip freeze --exclude-editable…   779B      buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   RUN /bin/sh -c pip3 install -e /obo/obo_lamb…   1.5kB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD extraction_events_lambda_handler /obo/ob…   109kB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   RUN /bin/sh -c pip3 install -e /obo/service_…   48.6MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD service_support /obo/service_support # b…   1.03MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   RUN /bin/sh -c pip3 install -e /obo/obo_aws_…   92.9MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD obo_aws_adapters /obo/obo_aws_adapters #…   405kB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   RUN /bin/sh -c pip3 install -e /obo/workflow…   1.65MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD workflow_detached_storage /obo/workflow_…   16.6kB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   RUN /bin/sh -c pip3 install -e /obo/storage_…   9.15MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD infrastructure_storage_layer /obo/storag…   227kB     buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 weeks ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL com.amazonaws.lambd…   0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ENTRYPOINT [ "/lambda-entrypoint.sh" ]          0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ENV LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/runtime             0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ENV LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT=/var/task                  0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/us…   0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ENV PATH=/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/b…   0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ENV TZ=:/etc/localtime                          0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8                            0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   WORKDIR /var/task                               0B        
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD file:6fe58d386e964379c6e7bb39227061f5b3e…   58.9MB    
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD file:0f6be89c61fa473b9f48e09d53e04e5a728…   205MB     
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD file:c95d9693c3e44862c9757c55b9ced6dcc4e…   6.25MB    
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD file:9cc8e28939500dd9d81d6234628ed8a4cfa…   397B      
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD file:d3902f3b33624e9104b60b6e60f212335ec…   658kB     
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ADD file:2709373cdba1b3f02b25f33dd15772e259c…   304MB     
<missing>      2 weeks ago   ARCHITECTURE amd64                              0B   

How does this happen? How is it possible that there's a row in the history that seemingly has no identity?

A layer in Docker is a filesystem diff. An image, on the other hand, specifies a stack of layers along with execution metadata: the environment variables, command to run, arguments, and so on.
When you build a Docker image, intermediate images are created to run each command in sequence. Those images will all be stored in Docker and visible in docker images. The sequence of commands used to construct the image will also be stored in the image's metadata under the history key, which is read by docker image history. That metadata looks like this (for python:3.12-alpine):
[
    {
      "created": "2024-07-22T22:26:43.622487881Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:99093095d62d0421541d882f9ceeddb2981fe701ec0aa9d2c08480712d5fed21 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-07-22T22:26:43.778747613Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "ENV LANG=C.UTF-8",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux; \tapk add --no-cache \t\tca-certificates \t\ttzdata \t; # buildkit",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0"
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "ENV GPG_KEY=7169605F62C751356D054A26A821E680E5FA6305",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.12.5",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux; \t\tapk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \t\tgnupg \t\ttar \t\txz \t\t\t\tbluez-dev \t\tbzip2-dev \t\tdpkg-dev dpkg \t\texpat-dev \t\tfindutils \t\tgcc \t\tgdbm-dev \t\tlibc-dev \t\tlibffi-dev \t\tlibnsl-dev \t\tlibtirpc-dev \t\tlinux-headers \t\tmake \t\tncurses-dev \t\topenssl-dev \t\tpax-utils \t\treadline-dev \t\tsqlite-dev \t\ttcl-dev \t\ttk \t\ttk-dev \t\tutil-linux-dev \t\txz-dev \t\tzlib-dev \t; \t\twget -O python.tar.xz \"https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz\"; \twget -O python.tar.xz.asc \"https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION%%[a-z]*}/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tar.xz.asc\"; \tGNUPGHOME=\"$(mktemp -d)\"; export GNUPGHOME; \tgpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys \"$GPG_KEY\"; \tgpg --batch --verify python.tar.xz.asc python.tar.xz; \tgpgconf --kill all; \trm -rf \"$GNUPGHOME\" python.tar.xz.asc; \tmkdir -p /usr/src/python; \ttar --extract --directory /usr/src/python --strip-components=1 --file python.tar.xz; \trm python.tar.xz; \t\tcd /usr/src/python; \tgnuArch=\"$(dpkg-architecture --query DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE)\"; \t./configure \t\t--build=\"$gnuArch\" \t\t--enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \t\t$(test \"$gnuArch\" != 'riscv64-linux-musl' && echo '--enable-optimizations') \t\t--enable-option-checking=fatal \t\t--enable-shared \t\t--with-lto \t\t--with-system-expat \t\t--without-ensurepip \t; \tnproc=\"$(nproc)\"; \tEXTRA_CFLAGS=\"-DTHREAD_STACK_SIZE=0x100000\"; \tLDFLAGS=\"${LDFLAGS:--Wl},--strip-all\"; \tmake -j \"$nproc\" \t\t\"EXTRA_CFLAGS=${EXTRA_CFLAGS:-}\" \t\t\"LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS:-}\" \t\t\"PROFILE_TASK=${PROFILE_TASK:-}\" \t; \trm python; \tmake -j \"$nproc\" \t\t\"EXTRA_CFLAGS=${EXTRA_CFLAGS:-}\" \t\t\"LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS:--Wl},-rpath='\\$\\$ORIGIN/../lib'\" \t\t\"PROFILE_TASK=${PROFILE_TASK:-}\" \t\tpython \t; \tmake install; \t\tcd /; \trm -rf /usr/src/python; \t\tfind /usr/local -depth \t\t\\( \t\t\t\\( -type d -a \\( -name test -o -name tests -o -name idle_test \\) \\) \t\t\t-o \\( -type f -a \\( -name '*.pyc' -o -name '*.pyo' -o -name 'libpython*.a' \\) \\) \t\t\\) -exec rm -rf '{}' + \t; \t\tfind /usr/local -type f -executable -not \\( -name '*tkinter*' \\) -exec scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' '{}' ';' \t\t| tr ',' '\\n' \t\t| sort -u \t\t| awk 'system(\"[ -e /usr/local/lib/\" $1 \" ]\") == 0 { next } { print \"so:\" $1 }' \t\t| xargs -rt apk add --no-network --virtual .python-rundeps \t; \tapk del --no-network .build-deps; \t\tpython3 --version # buildkit",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0"
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux; \tfor src in idle3 pydoc3 python3 python3-config; do \t\tdst=\"$(echo \"$src\" | tr -d 3)\"; \t\t[ -s \"/usr/local/bin/$src\" ]; \t\t[ ! -e \"/usr/local/bin/$dst\" ]; \t\tln -svT \"$src\" \"/usr/local/bin/$dst\"; \tdone # buildkit",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0"
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=24.2",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/66d8a0f637083e2c3ddffc0cb1e65ce126afb856/public/get-pip.py",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=6fb7b781206356f45ad79efbb19322caa6c2a5ad39092d0d44d0fec94117e118",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "RUN /bin/sh -c set -eux; \t\twget -O get-pip.py \"$PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL\"; \techo \"$PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256 *get-pip.py\" | sha256sum -c -; \t\texport PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1; \t\tpython get-pip.py \t\t--disable-pip-version-check \t\t--no-cache-dir \t\t--no-compile \t\t\"pip==$PYTHON_PIP_VERSION\" \t; \trm -f get-pip.py; \t\tpip --version # buildkit",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0"
    },
    {
      "created": "2024-08-07T15:49:22Z",
      "created_by": "CMD [\"python3\"]",
      "comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ]

When you docker prune, these intermediate images are deleted, and the only reference to those images will be in the history field of the final image. Similarly, if you pull an image from a repository, it will download only that image and the layers it references, but not the intermediate images.
docker image history correlates the history entries in the image metadata with the layer stack (skipping empty_layer entries) to produce the size field. If it can find the corresponding intermediate image, it'll display that; otherwise, it simply says that the intermediate image is <missing>.
Because images contain more information than just the layers, it's not possible to obtain the image or its digest from the history alone.

That's not accurate. As you're pulling an image, it even illustrates all of the data being downloaded for every constituent layer.

@DustinOprea You must distinguish layer from image. An image is a runnable entity in Docker, which contains not only the layers, but also information like the execution environment, run commands, etc. Layers are just filesystem diffs without that extra runnable context. Therefore, when you pull an image - you pull only the image and the layers that constitute it, not the intermediate images.
